# Having a Problem defining functions in Blender Python

Tags: python, add-on, error

I want to define a function that when called inside an operator by an enumerator update changes (and load if necessary) an image in a specific image node. this is the code

```
def MangaUseImage(filename, ImageNode):
    USER = Path(resource_path('USER'))
    ADDON = "Mangaka"
    
    FILE = filename
    srcPath = USER / "scripts/addons" / ADDON / "assets" / FILE
    srcFile = str(srcPath)
    
    if bpy.data.images.get(filename) is None:
        if Path(srcFile).is_file():
            Imported = bpy.data.images.load(srcFile, check_existing=True)
        else:
            print(f"The file at {srcFile} doesn't exist")
    else:
        pass
    try:
        NodeSet = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes['Main']
        global NodeIs
        NodeIs = NodeSet.node_tree.nodes.get(ImageNode)
        if NodeIs:
            NodeIs.image = filename
            
            #return (NodeSet)
        else:
            print(f'Error at setting {filename} as file for {ImageNode}')
    except:
        print('Node is not there yet')
    
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

How it's used inside an operator that gets updated on enumerator update

```
class Mangaka_OT_Config(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.config"
    bl_label = "Controls for Mangaka"
    
    def execute (self, context):
        scene = bpy.context.scene 
        MangaProp = scene.MangaProp
        
        if MangaProp.SelectTone4 == 'OP1':
            MangaUseImage('10%_60L600DPI.png', 'MainImageRed')
```

But I keep getting this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "\Rewrite.py", line 22, in MangakaUpdate
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.1\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 132, in __call__
        ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
    RuntimeError: Error: Python: RuntimeError: class OBJECT_OT_config, function execute: incompatible return value , , Function.result expected a set, not a NoneType
    
    location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.1\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py:132
    
    
    File "\Rewrite.py", line 21, in MangakaUpdate
```

What does this error means?

Comment: @MartyFouts nope it's perfect, didn't have time to form an answer so thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key part of this error message is "*function execute: incompatible return value , , Function.result expected a set, not a NoneType*"

The error is telling you that you have a function `execute` that is returning a value that is different than the value Python expects it to return.

This is because you are falling off of the bottom of your `execute` function without returning anything.  In Python that's defaulting to returning `None`.

But `execute` is expected to return a `set`  In fact [execute](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.execute) is meant to return a set of results from an enum.  In your case, you should end your `execute` function with

```py
return {'FINISHED'}
```

properly indented, of course.  Unless you want Blender to know your function failed, in which case `return {'CANCELLED'}`